# Identity server 3 - Showing a data capture screen just after login and before redirecting with token

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I need to capture few personal information of the user just after successful Identity server 3 login (Just like we show the consent screen), I need to save this details and then direct to the client url with token.

I just want to make this part of the Identity Login so that I can enforce this for all the different clients I have(android, angular, asp.net etc)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post code as well.

Comment: @AsthaSrivastava I don't have any code as of now, I am checking if this is possible in Identity server 3 and the procedure to do that